# Just leaking? Or undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

In an old implementation of a connection pool, I found this beauty (strongly simplified):

```
#include <memory>
#include <queue>

struct Connection
{
};

auto pool = std::queue<std::shared_ptr<Connection>>{};

auto pushConnection(Connection* connection) -> void
{
  // This uses pushConnection as custom deleter in the shared_ptr
  pool.emplace(connection, pushConnection);
}

int main()
{
  pushConnection(new Connection{});
}
```

The original idea was that you can obtain connections from the pool and once you are done, the custom deleter (`pushConnection`) would automatically return it to the pool.

However, storing the connections in the pool with the same custom deleter is more than just a little weird.

At bare minimum, there is a resource leak: When the pool goes out of scope at the end of the program, the destructor of `queue` will be called. This will destroy the `shared_ptr`s, which will call their custom deleter, which will emplace the connection back into the queue.

I wonder, if it is also undefined behavior to `emplace` into a `queue` that is currently in the process of being destroyed?

Comment: We cannot see any custom deleter for `Connection`. Can you elaborate on this part?

Comment: @tos-1 Updated the code with a comment: The custom deleter (`pushConnection`) is given to the `shared_ptr` in the `emplace` call.

Comment: I think I am getting something wrong. Is the intention of the code to produce an infinite loop? :) That is the result of "destructing a queue element inserts it, again".

Comment: There is no endless loop when the program is executed. `valgrind` confirms a memory leak. My question is: Is there undefined behavior, too?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread your original post. The memory leak stems from the `new Connection{}`. This object is never freed because the deleter of the owning shared pointer does not `delete` it. If the whole program is UB, I don't really know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented, the memory leak stems from the `new Connection{}`.

Is the program UB? I think it is.
`std::queue` uses `std::deque` as default container.
[The documentation of `std::deque::emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/emplace) says, that: "All iterators, including the past-the-end iterator, are invalidated."
Since the destructor of `std::deque` iterates over the elements, the result must be UB.

Comment: When the standard says an operation on a container invalidates all iterators, the meaning is that any iterators obtained BEFORE the operation are invalidated.   It doesn't mean that the container no longer has any valid iterators - if that was the case, the container would be unusable from that point.  Every call of a vector's `push_back()` member function invalidates all iterators, but it is fairly common to call that member function repeatedly, and then obtain iterators from the container in order to iterate over elements of the container.

Comment: @Peter what I mean is that the destructor must iterate over the elements. That most likely means that it holds iterators. If that is the case, these will get invalidated when the destructor of an element calls `emplace`.